# Difference between $location.path("/home") and $location.$$path="/home" in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, location, difference

I have a login page and a home page  in my sample POC.

When user completed signed in, then i have redirect  to home page from login page.

I have tried this below codes for redirecting to home page from login page using by `angular.$location`

### Code 1

```
 $location.path("/home");
```

This code is working good.No issues.

### Code 2

```
$location.$$path="/home";
```

*This code does not working probably, because the page is redirected, but URL is shown previous URL,**does not changed the redirected URL**.*

> - Why is this happened?
> - What is the difference between **code1** and **code2**

Comment: angularjs properties starting with `$$` should be considered private and not used, `.path()` does other things (ie, a history pushstate, or hashtag change), that changing the value of $$path does not do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$$path` is internal property of the angular you should not touch that.

if you see this code of location service in angular code base (https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/location.js#L480).

`$location.$$path = 'somepath'`, will only sets the $$path value

whereas,

`$location.path('somepath')` will do some other things also like calling `$$compose` internally and updating `this.$$url` and `this.$$absUrl` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Angular uses a single dollar ($) for some of their API methods, properties, and event names. Those methods are considered "public" and safe to use by developers.
They are documented and not likely to change much, but if they do change then the angular team will tell us about it.

When you see two dollars ($$) then you're best off just leaving that alone. You can of course use them any way you want (debugging is a good use), but you shouldn't need to. If you use them for your own purposes there's no guarantee it will even be there on the next minor version update so your code becomes more brittle.